# how to develop 2 level horizontal menu in flex3?

Tags: apache-flex

How can I develop a 2 level horizontal menu in flex 3? I want a sub menu to appear when you mouse over the 1st level.

Answer (score 0):

The `Menu` control has this functionality built in. Here's [Adobe's online documentation with some examples](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=menucontrols_5.html) for you to check out.

**Example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- menus/SimpleMenuControl.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" >

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            // Import the Menu control.
            import mx.controls.Menu;

            // Create and display the Menu control.
            private function createAndShow():void {
                var myMenu:Menu = Menu.createMenu(null, myMenuData, false);
                myMenu.labelField="@label";
                myMenu.show(10, 10);
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <!-- Define the menu data. -->
    <mx:XML format="e4x" id="myMenuData">
        <root>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem A" >
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem A-1" enabled="false"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem A-2"/>
            </menuitem>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem B" type="check" toggled="true"/>
            <menuitem label="MenuItem C" type="check" toggled="false"/>
            <menuitem type="separator"/>     
            <menuitem label="MenuItem D" >
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-1" type="radio" 
                    groupName="one"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-2" type="radio" 
                    groupName="one" toggled="true"/>
                <menuitem label="SubMenuItem D-3" type="radio" 
                    groupName="one"/>
            </menuitem>
        </root>
    </mx:XML>

    <mx:VBox>
        <!-- Define a Button control to open the menu -->
        <mx:Button id="myButton" 
            label="Open Menu" 
            click="createAndShow();"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: Forst of all thank you jason but this is not what am i asking        AAA BBBBBB CC DDD [1st level, B selected]
    aa bbb ccccc  [2nd level, options of B visible]                i hope now u can understand...

Comment: @Hari kanna, Yep, now I see what you want to do. This can be handled in several different ways depending on what your data looks like. Are your menus going coming in as an ArrayCollection? Are they hard coded and won't ever change?